# The correct way to initialize classes and stack overflow errors

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception, stack-overflow

This may be a stupid question, but I'm getting sick of this. How do you properly initialize a class object so you can access methods and variables in it? Here's my code:

```
public class GenChunk {

Chunk c;
VBO vbo;

int worldSize = 64;
int var1 = 16; //x
int var2 = 16; //z
int var3 = 16; //y

public GenChunk(){
    gen();
}

public void gen(){
    c = new Chunk();
    if(c.chunkChanged == false){
        for(int i = 0; i < worldSize; i++){
            newChunk();
        }
    }
}
```

The line `c = new Chunk()` is causing the stack overflow error., I realize why (because its creating new instances of it and taking up more and more memory), but as soon as I initialize it in the constructor or just do `Chunk c = new Chunk()`, at the top below `public class GenChunk {` I get another stack overflow error! If I don't initalize the class, I get a null pointer (obviously). What is wrong with my code? I must be overlooking something, but I can't figure it out!

Here is my Chunk class, it has a few empty methods:

```
public class Chunk {

public boolean chunkChanged = false;
boolean enteredGame = true;

public int chunkID = 0;

Player player;

float var1;
float var2;
float var3;

public Chunk(){
    update();
}

private void update(){
    setUp();
}

private void setUp(){
    if(enteredGame){
        new GenChunk();
    }
}

private void checkChunkRebuild(int id){

}

private void rebuildOnPlayerChange(int id){
    if(enteredGame && chunkChanged == true){

    }
}

private float getPlayerX(){
    return player.var1;
}

private float getPlayerZ(){
    return player.var2;
}

private float getPlayerY(){
    return player.var3;
}
```

}

Comment: Probably `Chunk` class is the culprit. Can you show that class?

Comment: Does Chunk() itself initialize a GenChunk object by any chance? Or any other infinite loop scenario... By the way, a public gen() method is NOT the proper way to initialize your instance.

Comment: Please submit Chunk code

Comment: You have an exception caused by the constructor of class Chunk, but you show neither this constructor, nor the exception stack trace. Why?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the chunk code in, I was so frustrated that I forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Chunk class is creating a new instance of GenChunk, which in turn is creating a new instance of the Chunk class, creating an infinite loop until the stack overflow occurs.

```
private void setUp(){
if(enteredGame){
    new GenChunk();
    }
}
```

is where it starts, and it continues at

```
public void gen(){
    c = new Chunk();
if(c.chunkChanged == false){
    for(int i = 0; i < worldSize; i++){
        newChunk();
    }
  }
}
```

which is called in the GenChunk constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In `GenChunk`'s constructor, you call `gen()`, which creates an instance of `Chunk`.

In `Chunk`'s constructor, you call `update()`, which calls `setUp()` which creates an instance of `GenChunk`.

This process repeats indefinitely. Thus the stack overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

- In your `GenChuck` constructor you create a new `Chunk` (via the `gen`) method.
- In your `Chunk` constructor you create a new `GenChunk` (via the `update`) method, `enteredGame`  is defaulted to true

This is a circular reference that is causing your stack overflow.

Comment: newChunk is actually a method in GenChunk that renders my VBO. But thanks!

Comment: I said new `Chunk`, not `newChunk`. In any case looks like you've marked an answer, good luck with the rest of the project.